# How to convert xml to list in C# or VB?

Tags: c#, xml, list

I need to convert xml to list in a particular format and I can't get my head around how to.

Below is the structure of xml. Under 'item' there can be unknown numbers of unknown items with values.

[image]

How can I transform to a list like below? The class i have is as below.

[image]

Basically, like this. There can be any numbers of item in there.

[image]

And finally use it like

```
var items = new List<item>();
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you looking to do this specifically using `XmlSerializer`, or are you open to using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LB2 .. Hi I have tried both. I tried XmlSerializer. It works great if i have a class structure with all the properties as unknown1, etc. But I just don't know how to do it dynamically.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein You can control deserialization performed by `XmlSerializer` by means of `IXmlSerializable` interface (though it can be a bit of a pain).

Comment: @LB2 Thanks .. I didn't know I can do select-many thing in Linq to xDocument .. Selman22's answer works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var items = xDoc.Root.Descendants("item")
            .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants()
                .Select(a => new Item
        {
            field = a.Name.ToString(),
            value = (string) a);

        }));
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know to use SelectMany in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways. I prefer to serialize objects into xml and back out again.

to write to your xml file:

```
var writer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<String>));
var xmlFile = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.xml"));
writer.Serialize(xmlFile, FileInfo);
```

and then to read from it:

```
var readFile = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.xml");
var reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<String>));
var oData = (List<String>)reader.Deserialize(readFile);
```

Edited to add:
To use your own class, just replace `List<String>` with your class name.